# Socket.io-client try to connect to my front URL

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I just created a new react app using the CRA tool, then I added axios, mui and socket.io-client. I have a backend running with a REST API and a Socket.io server.

But since the first time I loaded my react app, it started to automaticly connect to a socket.io server based on my front url (localhost:3030). Without any socket.io setup, so I don't really know how to stop it !

I made a simple Context to connect and store my real socket.io connection, and it works; but it also try to connect to ws://localhost:3030/ws anyway.

Do you have any idea of what is triggering this connection ?